# matching the variable name using lookup table and mutate function in R

Tags: r, lookup, dplyr

I am trying to match up the plot number using a lookup table and mutate function in R. The script worked but on certain date, the values are missing with no plot number assigned. I went back to check on the raw file and the data are there. But while using the lookup and mutate in those data, the data are missing.

```
lookup <- c("WH113C1" = "WH115B2","WH114C2" = "WH111A1","WH103C2"= "WH106B1","WH104C1" = "WH102A2")
trail2<-
  ApMay %>% mutate(Plot=lookup[as.character(Plot)])
```

The table are as follows:

```
 Plot      CanopyHeight  Date      Time date
 WH102A2    1712.169    4/25/2019   4   2019-04-25
 WH102A2    1712.169    4/25/2019   4   2019-04-25
 WH102A2    1728.224    4/25/2019   4   2019-04-25
 WH102A2    1728.411    4/25/2019   4   2019-04-25  
 WH102A2    1681.975    4/25/2019   4   2019-04-25
 WH102A2    1691.742    4/25/2019   4   2019-04-25
```

I do not where I am wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'lookup' should be constructed in the reverse way i.e. the names should be the one matching the values in 'Plot'

```
library(dplyr)
lookup1 <- with(stack(lookup), setNames(as.character(ind), values))    
ApMay %>%
       mutate(Plot=lookup1[Plot])
#   Plot CanopyHeight      Date Time       date
#1 WH104C1     1712.169 4/25/2019    4 2019-04-25
#2 WH104C1     1712.169 4/25/2019    4 2019-04-25
#3 WH104C1     1728.224 4/25/2019    4 2019-04-25
#4 WH104C1     1728.411 4/25/2019    4 2019-04-25
#5 WH104C1     1681.975 4/25/2019    4 2019-04-25
#6 WH104C1     1691.742 4/25/2019    4 2019-04-25
```

#### data

```
ApMay <- structure(list(Plot = c("WH102A2", "WH102A2", "WH102A2", "WH102A2", 
"WH102A2", "WH102A2"), CanopyHeight = c(1712.169, 1712.169, 1728.224, 
1728.411, 1681.975, 1691.742), Date = c("4/25/2019", "4/25/2019", 
"4/25/2019", "4/25/2019", "4/25/2019", "4/25/2019"), Time = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), date = c("2019-04-25", "2019-04-25", "2019-04-25", 
"2019-04-25", "2019-04-25", "2019-04-25")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: The code worked but I want the plot as WH115B2 instead of WH113C1. How does it work?

Comment: @SonisaSharma  IN your code, the key/value pair is `"WH104C1" = "WH102A2"`